# Why AES 256 GCM is more preferred by email service providers / banks over the fast and efficient ChaCha20 - Poly1305?

Tags: chacha, aes-gcm

This question is based on my recent observation of preferences of  certain email service providers and banks to use AES related symmetric ciphers over the more fast ChaCha20 Poly1305 . For example Google's Gmail browser version uses AES 128 GCM but Google's Search uses ChaCha20 Poly1305  ?

Is AES 128/256 GCM in any way more ***secure***  than ChaCha20 Poly1305 ?

Despite the fact that ChaCha20-Poly1305 uses processor friendly instructions for mobile devices, and easy to implement in software, why banks or financial institutions are reluctant to adopt it ?

Is it because of specific AES instructions on processors (as far as servers / PC/ laptops are concerned) or because they are sticking to old convention ?

Comment: They're essentially equally secure and mostly differ in some performance characteristics (ChaCha-Poly is better if no AES HW support is available which is somewhat rare these days). Also AES-GCM is standardized by NIST and I don't think ChaCha-Poly is (yet?).

Comment: @SEJPM If you are trying to encrypt files on a system, which would be better AES-GCM or Chacha20-Poly1305 ?

Comment: If you are working with the government of the US, you have to use AES!

Comment: @kelalaka I'm from India :)

Comment: [Does ChaCha20/Salsa have the same Bit Strength as AES for identical key sizes?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70936/18298), [Even a single AES-GCM nonce reuse can be catastrophic.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68525/18298) [What's the appeal of using ChaCha20 instead of AES?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/34455/18298)

Comment: AES 256 GCM has a lower security margin than chacha20poly1305 and it is more difficult to implement in software without timing attacks but it is easier to protect against power analysis attacks when implemented in hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AES-GCM is standardized by National Institute of Standards and Technology, the institution that drives standards for U.S. Federal agencies.

In some situations (think banking, government, large corporations) FIPS certification is desired and in order to pass FIPS certification you need to use approved algorithms.
When you check [FIPS 140-2 Annex A](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/140/2/final/documents/fips1402annexa.pdf), you see that AES-GCM is one of the approved 'security functions'. ChaCha20 Poly1305 is not.

Another reason is that ChaCha20/Poly1305 is a relatively newer design. AFAIK, it has been accepted as an IETF standard in 2015 [RFC7539](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539) while AES-GCM is a standard since 2007 ([NIST SP800-38D](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf)).

Moreover, AES has been around since 2000 and this means there is a lot of IP designs that have dedicated AES accelerators which make AES-GCM very efficient.

When it comes to security, AES is a very solid cipher and I would probably prefer it over Chacha20, but on the other hand GCM mode is very brittle and prone to implementation errors (think [IV abuse](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-16/materials/us-16-Devlin-Nonce-Disrespecting-Adversaries-Practical-Forgery-Attacks-On-GCM-In-TLS-wp.pdf)) and it may be considered less desirable in some implementation-related scenarios.