# Why does the Signal protocol use AES/CBC instead of AES/GCM?

Tags: aes, key-derivation, cbc, gcm, signal-protocol

[AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)/[GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) has obviously proved itself to be better than AES/[CBC](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/cipher-block-chaining). Unless the key is re-used with the same [initialization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) (see [disadvantages of GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18420/aes-gcm-disadvantage)). More information on its advantages against CBC can be found in [source 1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184305/why-would-i-ever-use-aes-256-cbc-if-aes-256-gcm-is-more-secure) and [source 2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135132/are-there-any-instances-where-aes-cbc-hmac-is-preferred-over-the-aes-gcm-mode).

Now, most protocols still use AES/CBC. I understand this in case a [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) is not used. But currently, I am reading about the [Signal Protocol](https://dspace.cvut.cz/bitstream/handle/10467/76230/F8-DP-2018-Rubin-Jan-thesis.pdf?sequence=-1) which also uses AES/CBC with [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) as the KDF.

So my question is: Why would Signal Protocol use AES/CBC when AES/GCM obviously has [better performance](https://kazoo.ga/quick-benchmark-cbc-vs-gcm/)?

### **EDIT**

I just tested (using [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)) AES/CBC vs AES/GCM on a Java implementation and AES/CBC actually beat AES/GCM in performance.
I am aware now why Signal Protocol uses AES/CBC but I don't understand how. [Signal documentation](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/#publishing-keys) (section 3.3 after the image) says

"Alice then calculates an "associated data" byte sequence AD that contains identity information for both parties".

And later says Alice sends "An initial ciphertext encrypted with some AEAD encryption scheme [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) using AD as associated data and using an encryption key which is either SK or the output from some cryptographic PRF keyed by SK."
Now I downloaded the Signal Protocol source (Java implementation) and did a search they never call [updateAAD](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#updateAAD(byte%5B%5D)) (a java function to set the additional authenticated data).

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you like AES-GCM but are worried about IV re-use, you really should be using [AES-GCM-SIV](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/102.pdf).

Comment: Thank you @IlmariKaronen but I am actually not worried since Signal Protocol uses KDF for each message meaning a new key is created for each mesasge (using HKDF) so as far as I know IV re-use isn't a problem as long as the keys aren't equal.

Comment: According to the link you posted, CBC has significantly better performance, which is to be expected especially with small packet sizes

Comment: @IlmariKaronen GCM-SIV has a significant overhead (+15% to +20%) over GCM. You cannot only recommend to use GCM-SIV when other alternatives could be studied to ensure no IV re-use.

Comment: Of course CBC beats GCM. GCM includes MAC calculation. A more fair comparison is CBC + HMAC or CMAC vs GCM. "Why" questions are often hard to answer. You could ask the authors of the protocol nicely? If you send them a well formatted mail then you will often get an answer. This worked even for PGP related questions where Phil Zimmermann responded here on the site.

Comment: Thank you @MaartenBodewes that was actually not obvious because in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode they say "Different block cipher modes of operation can have significantly different performance and efficiency characteristics, even when used with the same block cipher. GCM can take full advantage of parallel processing and implementing GCM can make efficient use of an instruction pipeline or a hardware pipeline. In contrast, the cipher block chaining (CBC) mode of operation incurs significant pipeline stalls that hamper its efficiency and performance."

Comment: You should focus on _security goals_ like _unauthenticated encryption_ (IND-CPA) or _authenticated encryption with associated data_ (AEAD), not on Rube Goldberg diagrams of how to wire block ciphers up named with acronym soup.  AES-CBC is an _unauthenticated_ cipher; AES-GCM is an _authenticated_ cipher.  As such they are incomparable even if they both have diagrams that you can put side by side and squint at.  You should look for where Signal _does_ do authentication: maybe it uses AES-CBC with HMAC-SHA256 in encrypt-then-MAC composition to _make_ an authenticated cipher, for instance.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Thanks for your help, with the details you just gave me I found out they do from looking at the class "org.whispersystems.libsignal.protocol.SignalMessage" and they append a 8 bytes HMAC result to an end of a message.

Comment: I'd be careful about comparing performance of AES Java as performance depends in part on which version you're using.  Oracle has put significant work into improving performance so the numbers you see could change over time.  Depending on the version you're using you might get an unoptimized software implementation, an optimized software implementation, a somewhat optimized implementation that takes advantage of hardware instructions or more optimized version that takes advantage of hardware instructions.

Comment: @Swashbuckler I tested on both Java 8 and Java 10, in both, CBC has won.

Comment: Actually, it seems like the authors of the Signal protocol endorse either option. See https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/, section 5.2, where it states, `This function is recommended to be implemented with an AEAD encryption scheme based on either SIV or a composition of CBC with HMAC`.